# CellEditor for JXTreeTable does not work

Tags: java, scroll, swingx, tablecelleditor

I'm trying to implement a JXTreeTable with scrollable cells.

I used custom TableCellRenderer and it looked good, but renderer does not handle events, therefore I added an custom editor to the JXTreeTable.

I thought the cells would be editable once I override isCellEditable() and let it return true anyway but It turned out not. Cells are still not editable, thus I cannot scroll the cells even there are scroll bars.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you post your code snippet, so that others can help? For my case it's editable once I override isCellEditable() and return true.